# Problems in Latex with bibtex and biblatex (bibliography)

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography

I'm using ubuntu16, i've intalled latex full version and texmaker. Im writing a document and when compiling the bibliography i get this message:
!LaTeX Error: File `bibtex.sty' not found. 
What can i do? S.O.S  its driving me crazy

```
\documentclass[12pto,a4paper,oneside]{book}

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}

\usepackage{bibtex}

\addbibresource{/chapters/reference.bib}

\begin{document}


blablablablablablablablablablablablab \parencite{author-bibliography}


\begin{appendix}
\end{appendix}


\listoffigures
\listoftables

\printbibliography


\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you need to use `\usepackage{biblatex}` instead of `\usepackage{bibtex}`.

Comment: Well it didnt work,  but thanks blackburn will continue searching

Answer (score -1):

Please fix the 1st line that should say 12pt

Be sure that bibtex is installed. On my computer tex live tools does the work.

Comment: Thanks for the observation pachamaltese, sophisticated nick btw, Im new in latex but until now i have found that TEXMAKER has lot of problems with bibliography. I have applied some tips and finally get the DAMN number to appear in the text BUT i can but for example: (pachamaltese, 2016) this i cant. Here are some thing i have done:

Comment: 1)check the configuration  options--configure texmaker--command--biblatex: bibtex %.aux  2)use the stupid pdflatex-biblatex-pdflatex pdflatex order to compile  3) try to match the bibtex version with the biber version I have now 2.5 and 3.5 so hope something is working i dont know  ....i ve been like 3 days searching for a solution

Comment: can you post a reproducible example?? texlive full should not be giving problems

Comment: there might be a problem with babel in spanish/portuguese
go to my website (pacha.hk) there I have posted a LaTeX thesis template that uses biblatex instead of bibtex

Comment: \usepackage[backend=bibtex,bibstyle=mla,style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{chapters/reference.bib}
\renewcommand\nameyeardelim{, }
\setlength{\bibitemsep}{\baselineskip}             >>>>>Im using this to write my bibliography but I cant remove all the parenthesis???

Comment: bang zhu wo qing wen, nice page btw

Comment: yes, you can't remove the parenthesis
the thing is that I did use biblatex because my university says that is the right citation format

Comment: 帮助我请问吗？
I did not understand the helping part. You can always check here http://ftp.inf.utfsm.cl/pub/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf
Writing in spanish or portuguese is a big problem when you need bibliographies or something else. Check the documentation if you need to use Chicago, IEEE, or another format.

Comment: well after struggling with that I found an already set latex thesis model, the only problem now is that it has a: file.tex    file.cls    file.bst   so this sort of script has its rules. Im struglling now trying to disable the bibliography and to put my own configuration of bibliography using: \usepackage[backend=biber,citestyle=authoryear,maxcitenames=2]{biblatex}

Comment: I turn off the configuration set for the bibliography to put mine instead and after doing the compilation pdflatex bibtex pdflatex sequence i got message: This is BibTeX, Version 0.99d (TeX Live 2015/Debian) The top-level auxiliary file: exemplo-diss.aux I found no \citation commands---while reading file exemplo-diss.aux I found no \bibdata command---while reading file exemplo-diss.aux I found no \bibstyle command---while reading file exemplo-diss.aux (There were 3 error messages)

Process exited with error(s)

Comment: it complies well in pdflatex but in bibtex thats when the message appears

Comment: please post a reproducible example or I can't really help much

Comment: http://wp.ufpel.edu.br/ppgmmat/documentos/          %this is the page where I got the model of  thesis for latex:  3. Modelo para digitação em Latex:  Modelo PPGMMat.......it uses a  file.tcl  and a file.bst   and the file Im working with its called:  exemplo-diss.tex    .......thats why I cant post a MWE(miniworking example) I want to use the same configuration of pages but to work with my own bibliogrphy style this means to turn off the bibliography config of the model

Answer (score -1):

I downloaded the .rar from your university.

Be sure that you have these packages installed:

- lastpage
- chngcntr
- babelbib

I did open exemplo-diss.tex and then I run latex+bibtex+latex and it works.